# Command line tools for modifying XSL

Tags: linux, shell, xslt, command-line-interface

What command line tools are available for working with XSL in UNIX environments. I would like to use proper tools rather than scripting languages such a `bash`,`sed` or `awk`.

Comment: So why mention `sed` and `awk` and tag the question with them!? I use the term question here very lightly as you haven't actually asked one.

Comment: And what do you ***want*** use?

Comment: obviously, the question is not clear. but I feel funny is, OP tagged awk and sed, because he does **not** want to use the two. :)

Comment: use Perl. Has many modules what correctly parses `xml` files... more precise question can lead to more precise answers...

Comment: Uhm, xmlstarlet and xsltproc are the obvious answers, since XSL is just XML too and thus can be modified with XSL again. (Can't add this as an answer, no idea why.)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a shell script that modifies a `.XSL` file

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Modified!" > file.XSL
```

*Use with caution!*

Comment: Thanks for the sense of humor shown ... the intend here was ...is there any tool available(like xmlstarlet is for xml) which can be used to modify xsl tags without bothering sed/awk .

Comment: @Sam I have rewritten your question but I still think its OT for SO.

Comment: @Sam XSL = XML based stylesheet language. Any tool what works with XML will "works" with XSL files too.